# How to manage concurrent users in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have to test a web application and I've been asked to test it with concurrent users over 10 minutes. I don't really know how to do it and if I can do it using `Forever`, `Pace` or something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
setUp(<YOUR SCENARIO>.inject(atOnceUsers(Configuration.NO_OF_USERS))).maxDuration(Configuration.MAX_DURATION minutes);
```

where `atOnceUsers` indicates the number of parallel requests.

Refer to [simulation setup](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/simulation/) for further documentation.